# Bash regex: replace string with any number of characters

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash

I'm trying to remove colouring codes from a string; e.g. from: `\033[36;1mDISK\033[0m` to: `DISK`

my regex looks like this: `\033.*?m` so match '\033' followed by any number of chars, terminated by 'm'

when I search for the pattern, it finds a match; `[[ "$var" =~ $regex ]]` evaluates to *true*

however when I try to replace matches, nothing happens and the same string is returned.

Here's my complete script:

```
regex="\033.*?m"
var="\033[36;1mDISK\033[0m"

if [[ "$var" =~ $regex ]]
then
        echo "matches"
        echo ${var//$regex}
else
        echo "doesn't match!"
fi
```

The problem appears to be with the match any number of any character part of the regex. I can successfully replace `DISK` but if I change that to `D.*K` or `D.*?K` it fails.

Note in all above cases the pattern claims to match the string but fails when replacing. Not too sure where to go with this now, any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `${something//something-else}` doesn't work with regex. What you need to do is use a capture group in your regex, then use `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to get the 1st captured substring, and so on.

Comment: Maybe you can somehow avoid having to strip the colouring in the first place. Did you try playing around with the ``TERM`` or ``COLORTERM`` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
$ var="\033[36;1mDISK\033[0m"
$ newvar=$(printf ${var} | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")
$ echo ${newvar}
```

returns:

```
DISK
```

Now verify!

```
$ echo $var | od
0000000 030134 031463 031533 035466 066461 044504 045523 030134
0000020 031463 030133 005155
0000026
$ echo $newvar | od
0000000 044504 045523 000012
0000005
```

Comment: thanks this works well, and certainly a more complete regex than my efforts!I had to make a minor adjustment: `newvar=$(printf ${var} | ...` to `newvar=$(printf "${var}" | ...` otherswise printf would only be passed the first word of a sentance

Answer (score 1):

To use the parameter expansion substitution operator, you need to use an extended glob.

```
shopt -s extglob
newvar=${var//\\033\[*([0-9;])m}
```

To break it down:

- `\\033\[` - match the encoded escape character and `[`.
- `*([0-9;])` - match zero or more digits or semicolons. You could use `+([0-9;])` to (more correctly?) match one or more digits or semicolons
- `m` - the trailing `m`.